# libreoffice convert all/specific sheet(s) from excel to csv

Tags: linux, excel, csv, libreoffice

How do I convert to CSV anything else than the first sheet of an excel file to CSV?

My current code is :

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv --outdir data/csv_files  data/excel_files/*.*
```

I would like to convert the n-th sheet, or even all sheets, not only the first one.

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

When saving as CSV, LibreOffice will only save the active sheet.  The command
 `libreoffice --convert-to` will use the first sheet.

Instead of using `--convert-to`, this is a relatively simple task with macros.  The macro just needs to activate a particular sheet and then save as CSV.  If you write a macro called "MyMacro1" that takes the name of a sheet, it can be run from the command line like this:

```
soffice macro:///Standard.Module1.MyMacro1("sheet 2")
```

Some example code is [here](http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2014-09-12/exporting-all-libreoffice-worksheets-csv).  Also keep [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) handy as a reference.

Alternatively, here is a solution using [xslx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv), which I have not tried: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/46466/how-to-convert-specific-sheet-to-csv-via-command-line/.

Comment: I haven't worked with libreoffice at all from command line. Where do I write / put the said macro?

Comment: Open LibreOffice and go to `Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic`.  Expand `My Macros / Standard` and select `Module1`.  Add the macro here, which will put it in the [user profile directory](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile) on your machine.

Comment: Can this be done from terminal, without the use of LibreOffice UI?

Comment: Are you asking how to write the macro using the terminal?  If so, you may be interested in writing in [python](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python), using a text editor such as vi.  Then copy the .py file to the user profile directory under `Scripts/python`.  Voilà -- no graphical UI involved!

Comment: What Python xls parser library did you use for the above?

Comment: The [UNO API](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) for LibreOffice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new option now on the CLI:

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/7.2#Document_Conversion

```bash
soffice --convert-to csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":44,34,UTF8,1,,0,false,true,false,false,false,-1 sample.ods --outdir data/csv_files
```